# Evaluation of a limit using L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to know if my understanding of the following is correct. This has been tripping me up for a long time now.

Compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x^{1-\beta}$.

This is part of a homework problem regarding the expectation of the Pareto distribution. It says everywhere that the expectation is for $\beta>1$ only, but what about $B=1$? Then doesn't the expectation change significantly because as you all have said, the limit at $\beta = 0$ evaluates to 1?

Could someone please clarify my doubt? Thanks.

Comment: For $\beta = 1$, you have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^0 = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} 1 = 1$.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule is not the right tool.

Comment: I have edited my question significantly to ask a more pertinent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f = \frac{x}{x^{\beta}} $$

If $\beta = 1$, then $\lim f = \lim 1 = 1 $

If $\beta > 1 $, then $ \beta - 1 > 0 \implies \lim f = \lim \frac{1}{x^{\beta - 1}} = 0  $

If $ \beta < 1 $, then $1 - \beta > 0 \implies \lim f = \lim x^{1 - \beta} = \infty  $

Answer (score 0):

Not quite: If $\beta = 1$, then $x^{1 - \beta} = x^0 = 1$ for all $x > 0$; hence, the limit is

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1 - \beta} = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1 = 1$$

You are correct for the other two, though.